# Can't change permission of folders: read-only file system error

Tags: permissions, directory

The owner only has permissions to **Access files**. Why can't I change the permission of this folder?

> Error setting permissions: Read-only file system

[image: screenshot with properties dialog and popup saying permissions could not be changed]

Comment: "Permissions" changing requires Write access to the parent directory.

Comment: I presume this concerns an external hard drive? What is the filesystem of the drive?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an overlay file system or external mount.
To see your mount points and their **rw/ro** state just run command `mount` and look for the path where the folder is located 
To have the write access enabled you can remount it with the command
`mount -o remount rw`

Answer (score 0):

It may not help on a read-only filesystem, but you can install krusader and run it with sudo, and try to change there.

P.S.: update after a comment:

install by `sudo apt install krusader` and then run it by typing `sudo krusader`

This may help you change permissions by right click-permissions, and if necessary, advanced permissions.

Comment: This answer is more of comment unless you put down the details here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have credentials to enable write access. If you do not have the ability, then this is a moot point. If you have the ability enable it and change the file permissions.